Would a 24V automotive system experience heavy parasitic draws from having a 24V to 12V converter fitted for retrofitting 12V lighting systems
As per my question, an old vehicle I'm working on only has a 24V supply system (2x12V batteries connected in series).
I was also hoping to implement an aftermarket central locking system too however all the 24V locking solenoids I've used have managed to fry their internals. So far the only sustainable implementation I've had is using 12V central locking solenoids pulling power from the 24V supply through a 24V>12V/20A converter. Currently waiting for a company to provide a 24V locking solenoid sample before I try again with 24V system specific parts.
My main concerns are:

Would there be increased parasitic draws from the converter being fitted?
Could I run into an accelerated degradation of the batteries due to the additional load?


1: depends on the converter. 2: depends on the batteries.

24V in a car is way better in every sense, just do as much as you can in 24V

can you put the converter behind a relay that only turns on when the lights are needed, or at least behind an ignition circuit, like the radio uses? #2 shouldn't be a problem for most regular cabin lighting.

@vir 1. would certain models work better for this kind of usage or scenario? 2. Standard 12V 60aH batteries connected in series for a classic truck.

@fraxinus the issue I've run into is that the 24V system seems to be quite niche, finding a lot of compatible parts is becoming incredibly costly or difficult.

@dandavis I was thinking about that. However I gave a bit more context in my original question. Additionally alongside the lights, I was hoping to retrofit and aftermarket central locking system too?

the constant draw from these is usually around 0.25-1.0W. If your battery was 50AH, that's 50-200 days to draw it flat.

@dandavis ah I see, well I've measured the parasitic drain and its coming upto be approximately 70mA. Could this be a contributing factor.

at 0.84W, if you drive it for an hour a month, that should be slightly more than enough to keep it topped off all the time.

I'll be doing a voltage drop test later today through all the existed and additional fuses I've added to see which circuit is the culprit. I'll let you know what I find, thank you for the help though :)

The converter will draw some bias current even when idle (no output load), so you likely need to shut the converter off when no lights are on if the vehicle will be idle for some time.  It won't degrade the battery operating life significantly, but it will slowly discharge it.  The allowed idle time is determined by the value of the converter idle current and the battery capacity.

If the truck was being used daily or near daily, would the bias current draw be enough to flatten it? I'm hoping that there isn't some specific battery property of 24V electrical systems that I'm missing with my logic?
